# Don't call onDestroy() of the parent Activity after calling startActivity()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an Activity with a lot of fragments transactions in it, and sometimes my users need to open the preferences Activity for a few seconds. I do it like this :

```
Intent preferencesIntent = new Intent(this, PreferencesView.class);     
this.startActivity(preferencesIntent);
```

Each time I do this, onDestroy() of my main Activity is called. So when my user are coming back, the main Activity is in it initial stage. But I would like the main Activity to be like when they leave it.

I know that I should save/restore my data and just let the Activity recreate itself. But this would be very complicated, and my users are in my main Activity most of the time.

So is there a way to tell Android not to kill my main Activity while it is not visible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use startActivityForResult(intent); in your case rather than simple startActivity(intent)

Comment: what device are you using? the system shouldn't be killing your first activity unless it has very little RAM

Comment: @FoamyGuy I'm using a Nexus 7. It has 1Gb of ram, and I have nearly no app opened.

Comment: @AbhinavSinghMaurya Thank you. But I already tried this one, and my parent Activity is still calling onDestroy().

Comment: post the code from your onPause, and onStop methods. The behavior you are describing is not normal for the system. It is likely something you have put into your activity is causing the behavior that you are witnessing.

Comment: I have no code in my onPause, onStop and onDestroy. So it is using the super() of the FragmentActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've alreay written the answer: save/restore state. This is how android works.

Your activity can be destroyed configuration change or something else.

Comment: If I don't have the choice, I will. But it seems to be a lot of trouble only for one really specific case. Moreover, reloading all my datas can take several seconds. I don't really like the user experience it is providing to my users.

Comment: you can store all your large data in fragment without view, use setRetainInstance(). this will save the fragment instance across configuration changes. That might look a bit complicated, however once you know how to do it, you will do it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can't prevent Android to stop an Activity.
The only way I see is to load the preferences in a Fragment in the main Activity.

Comment: The problem is that I'm also using Tabs, and one tab always need to be selected. Preferences wont fit in any of my tabs, so it would make a weird navigation.